# Adding a new table to tbody using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to add another row to this table in my HTML page. The table has four columns.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGAIb.png)

This is the code I have so far:

```
#Table Data
newVersion = soup.new_tag('td',{'colspan':'1'},**{'class': 'confluenceTd'})
newRow = soup.new_tag('tr')
newRow.insert(1,newVersion)
tableBody = soup.select("tbody")
#This is a magic number
soup.insert(tableBody[1],newRow)
```

I have only filled in one column (the version) and I have inserted it into the a `'tr'` tag. The idea being I could fill in the other 3 columns and insert them into the `tr`.

The `tableBody[1]` is due to the their being multiple tables on the page, which don't have unique IDs or classes.

The problem line is the `soup.insert(tableBody[1],newRow)` as it raises:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Tag'
```

But how do I provide a reference point for the insertion of the tr tag?

Comment: Please post code and not Images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new tag with different attributes, you can use the `attr` parameter of `new_tag`.

> `newVersion = soup.new_tag('td', attrs= {'class': 'confluenceTd', 'colspan': '1'})`

Since you haven't provided any HTML code, I have tried to reproduce the HTML code based on your input.

This code will append the newly created row to the `tbody`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = '''
<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">1.0.17</td>
        <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">...</td>
        <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">...</td>
        <td colspan="1" class="confluenceTd">...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
newVersion = soup.new_tag('td', attrs= {'class': 'confluenceTd', 'colspan': '1'})
newRow = soup.new_tag('tr')
newRow.insert(1,newVersion)
tableBody = soup.select("tbody")
#This is a magic number
tableBody[0].append(newRow)

print(soup)
```

```
Output

<table>
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">1.0.17</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">...</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">...</td>
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">...</td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1"></td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```